# possible regression? type error compiling using ghc 9.6.2, hmatrix 0.20.2, and Vector 0.13.0.0

Tags: haskell, hmatrix

Compiling the following code using ghc 9.6.2, hmatrix 0.20.2, and Vector 0.13.0.0

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as V

nnz :: Vector R -> Int
nnz v = size $ V.filter (/= 0) v

avg :: Vector R -> R
avg v = V.sum v / fromIntegral (size v)
```

gets the following errors:

```
 ghc hvBug.hs
Loaded package environment from /Users/gcolpitts/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-9.6.2/environments/default
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( hvBug.hs, hvBug.o )

hvBug.hs:6:32: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match expected type: V.Vector t0
                  with actual type: Vector R
      NB: ‘V.Vector’
            is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Storable’ in package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’
          ‘Vector’
            is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Storable’ in package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’
    • In the second argument of ‘V.filter’, namely ‘v’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘V.filter (/= 0) v’
      In the expression: size $ V.filter (/= 0) v
  |
6 | nnz v = size $ V.filter (/= 0) v
  |                                ^

hvBug.hs:9:15: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match expected type: V.Vector R
                  with actual type: Vector R
      NB: ‘V.Vector’
            is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Storable’ in package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’
          ‘Vector’
            is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Storable’ in package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’
    • In the first argument of ‘V.sum’, namely ‘v’
      In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘V.sum v’
      In the expression: V.sum v / fromIntegral (size v)
  |
9 | avg v = V.sum v / fromIntegral (size v)
  |               ^
```

Note that [https://dis.um.es/~alberto/hmatrix/hmatrixtut.html#types](https://dis.um.es/%7Ealberto/hmatrix/hmatrixtut.html#types) says:

> We can also import qualified Data.Storable.Vector as V to use any desired
> function from the vector package.

I believe this code used to compile and thus that it may be a regression in ghc 9.6.2, hmatrix 0.20.2, or Vector 0.13.0.0

At https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.0.0/changelog I see:

> One consequence of this choice is that it is no longer possible to coerce between Storable.Vector a and Storable.Vector b if a and b are nominally distinct but representationally equal types. We now provide unsafeCoerce{M}Vector and unsafeCast functions to allow this (the onus is on the user to ensure that no Storable invariants are broken when using these functions).

Is it possible that this is the cause of the error? If so how do I change the code so that it compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to compile your example with Stack `nightly-2023-09-09` using the same GHC, hmatrix, and vector packages as you, so I believe this is a problem with your globally installed `hmatrix` and `vector` packages.

One clue is this part of the error message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type: V.Vector t0
              with actual type: Vector R
  NB: ‘V.Vector’
        is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Storable’ in package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’
      ‘Vector’
        is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Storable’ in package ‘vector-0.13.0.0’
```

It is not normal for GHC to refer to the same identifier in the same package with two different qualified names, or a qualified name plus an unqualified name, as has happened here.

What has probably happened is that your `hmatrix` package was built and installed against one build of `vector-0.13.0.0`, and then `vector-0.13.0.0` was rebuilt.  Even though these packages have the same name and version, they are not recognized as the same package, and the qualified name `V.Vector` imported from `Data.Vector.Storable` and the unqualified `Vector` imported from `Numeric.LinearAlgebra` are not recognized as referring to the same type.

Assuming you're trying to use Cabal to globally install packages, I'd suggest running:

```
cabal install --reinstall --lib vector-0.13.0.0
cabal install --reinstall --lib hmatrix-0.20.2
```

and then try recompiling your program.

(Actually, I'm a little worried this won't work.  In my testing, `cabal` seemed to ignore the `--reinstall` flag.)

Comment: Thanks @K.A. Buhr! I basically deleted all packages , reinstalled and it now works. It's more complicated than that but no room in a comment to document all that I did. IMHO cabal seems broken with respect to global packages

Comment: @GeorgeCo That is a popular opinion, and is the motivation for the modern nix-style builds. I encourage you to use them; usually it's as easy as typing `cabal init`, making a few tweaks to the `.cabal` file it creates, and using `cabal build` instead of using `ghc` directly.